# Show data in html from database

Tags: asp.net, database, datatable, dataset, eval

I have a select query which is return just one row data. I want to show them some different part of a page, not in a repeater, datalist etc...
I do not use asp:label or somtehing like that, then how can I show them from client side like eval or how can I bind Codebehind and call them from client side in html?

edit:

codebehind:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); ;
    dt = myprocedur.User_Load(Int32.Parse(Session["User_ID"].ToString())).Tables[0];
```

That I want to bind it something or somewhere in page Load.

Then in HTML:

```
<div><%#Eval("User_Name") %><div>
```

Use like that where I want, whithout `<asp:blabla runat:server />`, what is the way of that?
If is it possible, can you give me some exapmle?

edit2:
c#

```
public static string getData()
{
return "abcd";
}
```

html

```
<div><%getData%></div>
```

I guess we can use st like that, can we adapt it for data from database or similar way for it?

Comment: have you tried literal control

Comment: Nope, I do not want to write them with code behind.
Is it possible to do that like repeater with eval or st. like that?
Just I want to put  `<%name%>` or st like that where I like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Form View` ,

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
 DataSourceID="yourDataSource">

<ItemTemplate>
   <%# Eval("User_Name") %>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

You can reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx) !

In my example , I use `DataSourceID="yourDataSource"` , if you want to bind fromView's data source from code behind , you can bind likes

```
FormView1.DataSource = yourDataSoruse ;
FormView1.DataBind();
```

**Edit**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); ;
dt = myprocedur.User_Load(Int32.Parse(Session["User_ID"].ToString())).Tables[0];
FormView1.DataSource = dt ;
FormView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: should I use Itemtempalte and formview? I need these datas variable places... How can I adapt it?